# Trying to figure out a showHide function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a e-commerce site for a client that I picked up when I started a new job. It's on 3D Cart if anyone is familiar with that system. There is an accordion menu on the main frame page.  There is this piece of script coding on there:

```
function showHide(divId)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display === 'none')
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display='inline';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

The rest of the page is set up in a table format. I am wanting to know if that script code could be/is what is being used to control a line of code like this:

```
<td width="13" height="13" style="padding-top:3px;">
        <a class="BoxLink" href="#" onclick="showHide('spraybooths');return false;"><img src="https://example.com/assets/images/default/menu_tree_plus.gif" border="0" alt=""/></a>
        </td>
        <td height="13" style="padding-top:3px;" class="BoxText">
        <a class="BoxLink" href="https://example.com/UNICURE-SPRAYBOOTHS_c_1.html">UNICURE SPRAYBOOTHS</a>
        </td>
```

The accordion opens correctly, but once you choose a link it closes back down and I am trying to figure out how to keep it open. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I will provide as much information as I can if more is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the event propagates. Assuming you don't want to close the div when you click on a link inside it, you can write:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div a').addEventListener('click', 
   function(ev){ ev.stopPropagation
}, false);
```

Comment: I am not a javascript person so please forgive me..    so would that line of code need to go in my div where the onclick function would be located?

Comment: The line of code should be independent from other event handlers. Basically, what the line does, is forbidding the links inside the div from alerting the rest of the as being clicked. It's like telling the links to keep the click event to themselves.

Comment: So then should that event handler go in the script section at the top of  the page or do I have to put that in every table cell to control that function?

Comment: What do you mean "every table cell"? The script should only go where you have other event handlers.

Comment: This menu is built in a table, not with div tags.  If you look at my original post. I have the script tags that are in the header and then a portion of one of the tables with one link in it. I have like 50 of them that make up this entire menu. That's why I am asking if I need to put that into every table cell.

Comment: Then use `document.querySelectorAll('th a')` to select all table headers(?). Basically, whatever wrapper that contains the links, use it.

Comment: No. I have tried changing that to every part of the table and none of those seem to work. The menu still close back when a link is selected.

Comment: How about `var headerLinks = document.querySelectorAll('th a'); [].forEach.call(headerLinks, function(e){ e.addEventListener('click', function(ev){ev.stopPropagation()}, false)});`



I think with some browsers, you can't add event listeners to a group of elements. Try that (make sure `headerLinks` is actually a group of link elements that you want - adjust accordingly) and let me know if it fails (it shouldn't!)

Comment: I will try that, but I put this same question on a different forum and got this response:                                                                                 as it is I don't think you can. that anchor directs you to a new page. for example on page https://spraybooths-com.3dcartstores...-360_c_65.html the link will take me to https://spraybooths-com.3dcartstores...gies_c_63.html (just an example anchor I drilled down to) that means you would need to actually call that page with a query string, write a script to read those params and then re-set the expanded menus accordingly.